# Horizontally align text within absolute position

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to draw out a box. Within this box, I want to position some elements in the top left and right corners, then draw additional elements below that, hugging the bottom of the box, but no longer in the corners.

In the case of the bottom left element, I want it to be centered within the left column/half of the box whereas I want the bottom right element to be right aligned within its right column/half of the box.

I have created a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/7GeAM/2/ to illustrate what I'm getting at. I've used `position:absolute;bottom:0` in order to align the bottom texts to the bottom of the box, however the text-align properties no longer appear to do anything.

What can I do to achieve these alignments once again? Thanks!

Edit: I have updated the jsfiddle to use the stylesheet. The goal is to preserve the placement of the text at the bottom within each of the columns. In the bottom left, I wish to center the text within its column. In the bottom right, I wish to right-align the text, also within its column.

Comment: Why do you use inline `style` attribute? isn't it easier to write a stylesheet? And btw it's not clear at all what you want to achieve, I'm lost in the alignments... :|

Comment: It's far easier to write a stylesheet - I just did that for the purpose of a quick and easy example to present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the divs a width for text alignment to work. For example, you could make them each take up half the width of the box:

```
.bottom-left {
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
}

.bottom-right {
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6v6W/

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7GeAM/3/)***

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="float-left-50">
        <div class="cell">
             <p class="text-left">Top Left</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
             <p class="abs-bottom text-center">Bottom center</p>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="float-left-50">
        <div class="cell">
            <p class="text-right">Top Right</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <p class="abs-bottom text-center">Bottom Center</p>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

.container {
    position:relative;  
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:400px;
}
.text-left { text-align:left; }
.text-right{ text-align:right; }
.text-center{ text-align:center; }
.float-left-50{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
.cell{
    position:relative;
    width:198px;
    height:98px;
    border:1px dashed #aaa;
    background:#eee;
}
.abs-bottom{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```